# What's so cool about local compactness?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, algebraic-number-theory, examples-counterexamples, topological-groups

As I study more algebraic number theory, I hear more and more often about local compactness: *locally compact fields*, *locally compact topological groups*, *Stone-Čech compactification of locally compact spaces*, etc. etc.

In one paper, I even read that proving what the characters of $\Bbb {Q_p, R}$ are is  trivial using properties of locally compact spaces.

So I am wondering, what are all those nice properties, and what kind of (counter-)examples should I keep in mind when thinking about local compactness?

Comment: AFAIK, local compactness + Hausdorff allows you to develop/extend methods of calculus, using Haar measures.

Comment: Locally compact groups are the objects on which we can do analysis

Comment: Specifically, Harmonic Analysis.

Comment: It's like compactness, but just locally. And compactness is the beeswax of topology!

Comment: In some of your examples, compactness is too strong a requirement, and local compactness is the next best thing you can hope for: no infinite topological field is compact.

Answer (score 5):

Every locally compact Hausdorff space is [Tychonoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_space), hence it has "enough" continuous functions. This is used extensively. A prominent example is the proof of [Gelfand duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_duality): If we associate to a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ the $C^*$-algebra $C(X)$ of complex continuous functions, then we obtain an anti-equivalence of categories between locally compact Hausdorff spaces and commutative $C^*$-algebras (with suitably defined morphisms).

Technical but important: If $Y$ is locally compact, then for all spaces $X,Z$ the map
$$C(X,C(Y,Z)) \to C(X \times Y,Z)$$
is well-defined and bijective (*exponential law*). The special case $Y=[0,1]$ shows that a homotopy between continuous maps $X \to Z$ is really just a map from $X$ to the path space $C(I,Z)$.

Quite related to the exponential law: If $Y$ is locally compact, then $Y \times -$ preserves quotient maps (this doesn't hold for arbitrary $Y$, although many topologists use this, perhaps having in mind a *[convenient category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convenient+category+of+topological+spaces)* of spaces).